# prevent multiple posts in react/mongoose

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, redux, python-requests

I'm working on an app in reactjs/redux with mongoose. I have form which allows to auth ppl add a comment to the article but if user clicks like 10 times in 1 second form gonna send 10 requests.. which is bad. How can I prevent this? 
Let's say user clicks once on a button and then he needs to wait 5 seconds to send another comment.

Answer (score 1):

As for the frontend part, you can add a timestamp to the component state or redux, something like `lastPostTime` for that user and then compare it to the current time and if it's less than 5 seconds or other timeframe that you want to prevent the post, make the button disabled.

Here is some imaginary component example:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      lastPostTime: null
    };
    this.handleCommentSubmit = this.handleCommentSubmit.bind(this);
    this.checkIfTimeoutPassed = this.checkIfTimeoutPassed.bind(this);
  }

  handleCommentSubmit(e) {
    if (this.checkIfTimeoutPassed()) {
      console.log('sent');
      this.setState({ lastPostTime: Date.now() });
    }
  }

  checkIfTimeoutPassed() {
    const postTimeOut = 5000;
    const { lastPostTime } = this.state;
    const timeSinceLastPost = Date.now() - lastPostTime;
    return !lastPostTime || timeSinceLastPost > postTimeOut;
  }

  render() {
    return (<button onClick={this.handleCommentSubmit}>Click me</button>);
  }
}
```

It would make sense to make a similar checks on the backend in case the user will hack through the frontend limitations.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was very angry about multiple requests in few time and cannot share my website in production for this reasons !